# jQuery rating not working on live

Tags: jquery

[rating](http://qa.ukatn.com/totallydriven/feedback/feedback-form.php?fid=1&rno=TA20021)

This is my URL, I am using jquery.ratings.js.

But when I run the page, it is saying

```
("#test-2").ratings is not function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this could be the reason (from the page source you linked to):

```
<!--<script src="star-rating/jquery.ratings.js"></script>-->
```

Generally commenting out the script tag to load the ratings plug-in will cause it not to work :)

Comment: can some one tell me the exact reason please, why star not working for me

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for that function to not register is the previous JS error on the page: "AC_FL_RunContent is not defined".  Changing your AC_RunActiveContent.js path from `js/AC_RunActiveContent.js` to `../js/AC_RunActiveContent.js` should fix that.  If that doesn't work you may want to try a different rating plugin, such as this one: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed.

The thing is, two time `jquery.js` called so that.